# Globalization directly resuscitates local traditions

Tags: paradox, zizek

I saw this on Wallerstein's writing, and I am not sure how one leads to this conclusion.

What is the source of this quote, "Globalization directly resuscitates local traditions", and how does one lead to this conclusion?

(The quote seems to be made by Slavoj Zizek, though I am not sure.)

Comment: Is there any chance I might be able to persuade you to tell us a little more about the context and motivations of your concerns?

Answer (score 3):

The full quote is:

> [T]he opposition between globalization and local traditions is false:
>   globalization directly resuscitates local traditions, it literally
>   thrives on them, which is why the opposite of globalization is not
>   local traditions, but universality.

from chapter IV of *The Ticklish subject*.

This appears to be an extension of Zizek's inheritance of the critique of capitalism from [Frankfurt school critical theory](http://www.iep.utm.edu/frankfur/). In short, the argument follows the line of globalism allowing local traditions to be taken hold of by Occidental ideological and market mechanisms, (think for eg. dream catchers), reinvigorating the particularities of local tradition in a movement akin to the opposite of cultural homogenisation (or 'universality'), meaning capitalism thrives most successfully when these elements of local culture are preserved and recirculated.

Comment: An interesting paradox, right? Nice job tracking this down

Comment: I find it hard to agree, it thrives on them yes, we are always interested and entertained by the other, but it ends its homage by homogenisation

Comment: @ Mozibur Ullah interesting, are you able to unpack this a little further?  Joseph Weissman 'tis an interesting paradox, very in line with the 60s-70s-80s ideas of France, the ontological primacy of difference over order, i remember in an EGS lecture by Badiou a similar opposition, moving away from perspectives grounded the establishment of 'universal rights' and framing protest within the universality of struggle and discord. Difference always preceding determinations of harmony .. i'll have to dig out some books, also remember fractal ontology having some interesting engagements with Zizek..

Comment: @DrSister: On the cultural level difference is a locus of attractiveness for capital, like energy moving from warm to cold. But in doing so it destroys the authenticity of that tradition. A tradition preserved for the outside gaze is no longer a tradition, it's a tourist attraction. For an attraction like the pyramids or the Taj Mahal this may not be no bad thing; but when it comes to socio-economic and cultural traditions it may be a tragedy. Tagore, the Indian poet, wrote about just this rivitalisation about Japan at the beginning of the 20C. Japan was moderninsing, and Tagore wasn't

Comment: against this, he approved of science/technology, but he was against the militarisation of their society which he felt was imitation of European nationalism/fascism at the time. As he predicted it ended in disaster. Difference can be and is a revitalising source, but it can also overwhelm. What do you mean by the 'ontological primacy of difference over order?' It's a Deleuzean term, right?

Comment: Indeed it is, but not in the sense of difference being the product of disparity between 2 seperate entities, difference is a primary and productive force, Deleuze elaborates not a difference between concepts but a concept of difference. I'd like to write more when i have time, thanks for the continued interest :)